How to evenly distribute objects in an area without overlapping?
Input data:
square = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))

obj_1st = np.array([
    [1.0, 8.0, 0, 3.0, 8.0, 0, 3.0, 6.0, 0, 1.0, 6.0, 0, 1.0, 8.0, 0], 
    [6.0, 7.0, 0, 8.0, 7.0, 0, 8.0, 5.0, 0, 6.0, 5.0, 0, 6.0, 7.0, 0], 
    [3.0, 4.0, 0, 5.0, 4.0, 0, 5.0, 2.0, 0, 3.0, 2.0, 0, 3.0, 4.0, 0]
])

obj_2nd = np.array([
    [2.0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 4.0, 0, 4.0, 3.0, 0, 2.0, 3.0, 0], 
    [2.0, 6.0, 0, 3.0, 7.0, 0, 4.0, 6.0, 0, 2.0, 6.0, 0], 
    [7.0, 3.0, 0, 8.0, 4.0, 0, 9.0, 3.0, 0, 7.0, 3.0, 0]
])

I have a square, and I have objects that lie in that square. obj_1st are square objects, obj_2nd are triangular objects.
The task is to distribute these objects evenly over the square so that the objects do not overlap.
My code performs almost the functionality I need. But the distribution of objects looks ugly and uneven.

# Function to check if objects are overlapping
def areObjectsOverlapping(obj1, obj2):
    x1 = obj1[:, 0::3]
    y1 = obj1[:, 1::3]
    x2 = obj2[:, 0::3]
    y2 = obj2[:, 1::3]
    return not (np.max(x1) < np.min(x2) or np.min(x1) > np.max(x2) or np.max(y1) < np.min(y2) or np.min(y1) > np.max(y2))

# Function to move an object
def moveObject(obj, vector):
    obj[:, 0::3] += vector[0]
    obj[:, 1::3] += vector[1]
    return obj

# Square and objects
square = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 10, 10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

obj_1st = np.array([
    [1.0, 8.0, 0, 3.0, 8.0, 0, 3.0, 6.0, 0, 1.0, 6.0, 0, 1.0, 8.0, 0], 
    [6.0, 7.0, 0, 8.0, 7.0, 0, 8.0, 5.0, 0, 6.0, 5.0, 0, 6.0, 7.0, 0], 
    [3.0, 4.0, 0, 5.0, 4.0, 0, 5.0, 2.0, 0, 3.0, 2.0, 0, 3.0, 4.0, 0]
])

obj_2nd = np.array([
    [2.0, 3.0, 0, 3.0, 4.0, 0, 4.0, 3.0, 0, 2.0, 3.0, 0], 
    [2.0, 6.0, 0, 3.0, 7.0, 0, 4.0, 6.0, 0, 2.0, 6.0, 0], 
    [7.0, 3.0, 0, 8.0, 4.0, 0, 9.0, 3.0, 0, 7.0, 3.0, 0]
])

objects = [obj_1st, obj_2nd]

# Algorithm to avoid overlapping and stay within the square
while True:
    overlap = False
    for i in range(len(objects)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(objects)):
            if areObjectsOverlapping(objects[i], objects[j]):
                overlap = True
                vector = (np.mean(objects[i][:, 0::3]) - np.mean(objects[j][:, 0::3]), np.mean(objects[i][:, 1::3]) - np.mean(objects[j][:, 1::3]))
                objects[i] = moveObject(objects[i], vector)
                objects[j] = moveObject(objects[j], [-v for v in vector])
                
                # Check if objects move outside the square, then move them back inside
                for obj in objects:
                    obj_x_min = np.min(obj[:, 0::3])
                    obj_x_max = np.max(obj[:, 0::3])
                    obj_y_min = np.min(obj[:, 1::3])
                    obj_y_max = np.max(obj[:, 1::3])
                    
                    if obj_x_min < 0:
                        move_dist = -obj_x_min
                        obj = moveObject(obj, (move_dist, 0))
                    elif obj_x_max > 10:
                        move_dist = 10 - obj_x_max
                        obj = moveObject(obj, (move_dist, 0))
                        
                    if obj_y_min < 0:
                        move_dist = -obj_y_min
                        obj = moveObject(obj, (0, move_dist))
                    elif obj_y_max > 10:
                        move_dist = 10 - obj_y_max
                        obj = moveObject(obj, (0, move_dist))
                        
    if not overlap:
        break

# Plotting
def plot_lines(coords):
    for obj in coords:
        x = obj[0::3]
        y = obj[1::3]
        plt.plot(x, y)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plot_lines(square)
for obj in objects:
    plot_lines(obj)

plt.title('Square and Objects without Overlapping')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.grid(True)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()



@Elerium115, Specifically in my problem, I need to find an algorithm to distribute objects evenly over the domain. Do you need an example?

Ok, so your objects don't look "ugly". Instead you have a metric of how evenly distributed are those objects. Your algorithm scores low on this metric and you want to improve it. Could you share the calculation of the metric and your current score?  Except for the brow triangle, which should get more to the right, the rest of the objects seem to be quite evenly distributed.

@Elerium115, So far, I have found a quasi-random R-squared method that distributes points evenly in the area. I need something like this - https://prnt.sc/qfQN26dYdo6c.
In this example, all points are connected evenly. I need my objects to be evenly distributed in the area.

@Elerium115, Also, some objects lie on the border of the square. In my case, that's not right. And just like that, a evenly distribution will solve this problem

A uniform distribution won't solve the border problem unless you add code to avoid being too close to the margin (look at the example picture you posted and you will see that not only the border is not avoided, but also some points overlap the border). Avoiding the border is as easy as defining your allowed area with a certain margin to the border.

@Elerium115, And what do I need to use to get the results I want?

@BobbyLith, your posts are often of low quality and always end up being a moving target. The visualizations you show never match with the sample inputs. Here, your code gives this (the outer square is not closed). You really need to take a step back before posting and, read How to Ask to make a Minimal-Reproducible-Example.

@Elerium115, I'm sorry, I really made a mistakes. I'll look into the article you sent. I have updated the code in my post. Now the result matches the picture.
